# Why windows cannot show image file dimensions with size more than 4Gigabytes?

Tags: windows-7, images

When we click on image files, Windows shows its dimensions at the bottom of the window. When file size is more than 4 GB, then Windows cannot show the dimensions.

Why is this? How can I get it to show the dimensions?

Comment: Which image format? Or all of them? What do you use to view images? Because for example JPEG has it's dimensions in the header, before the data comes. So it shouldn't have problems to show dimensions.

Comment: @ap0 , my images are tiff (written by bigtiff library) and I don't open them, only click on them to find it's dimention in the bottom of the window.